# Unable to find position of the first occurrence in a string

Tags: php, strpos

I need to find position of the first character occurrence in a string that does not repeat. So far all I have my `$pos` outputs `0`.

```
<?php
$sentence = "some long string";
$found = false;

while(!$found && $sentence!== ""){
  $c = $sentence[0];
  $count = substr_count($sentence,$c);

  if ($count == 1) $found = true;
  else $sentence = str_replace($c,"",$sentence);
}
$pos = strpos($sentence, $c);
echo "$c: $pos";
```

It wil output `l:0`. What's up with that?

I understand that `$pos = strpos($sentence, $c);` will not be the correct way to find position. Why Im confused is, when I echo $c its value is "l". So, I thought if i use its value in strpos it will give me the correct position. So to get help on how to extract this first non repeating character position, i thought I would ask at StackOverlow to point me to the right direction. No need to be d**ks, I just learning and I appreciate the help.

Comment: Whats the problem? `$c = $sentence[0];` It _is_ the 0th index? :?

Comment: What exactly are you searching for within `$sentence`?

Comment: This is terribly convoluted. It's not clear what you are trying to do, but whatever it is, it can probably be done much more simply.

Comment: I need to find position of the first character that does not repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is nearly correct. When I tested it I got 'm: 0', which is indeed the first character only to appear once. The reason the position is 0 is that you have been shrinking the original string every time you tried a new character.

I suggest you copy the string before you start looking for characters in it, and then use the copy to calculate the position at the end, rather than the diminished string.

```
<?php
$sentence = "some long string";
$sentence_copy = $sentence;
$found = false;

while(!$found && $sentence!== ""){
  $c = $sentence[0];
  $count = substr_count($sentence,$c);
  if ($count == 1) $found = true;
  else $sentence = str_replace($c,"",$sentence);
}

$pos = strpos($sentence_copy, $c);
echo "$c: $pos";
```

This gives me 'm: 2', which is correct.

Comment: Thank you. Many likes :) If I could give you points up, I would. Unfortunately some ignorant people disliked my post and I cant til i turn 15 again.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the comment

> I need to find position of the first character that does not repeat.

```
<?php
$numberOfOccurences = array_count_values(str_split($string, 1));
$uniqueCharacters = array_keys(
    array_filter($numberOfOccurences, function($c) { return $c == 1; })
);
echo $uniqueCharacters[0] . ':' . strpos($string, $uniqueCharacters[0]);
```

The idea is simply, that we treat the string not as a string, but as a set of characters, count every character, then only keep the characters, that appears once (`$c == 1` in `array_filter()`) and (assuming, that the functions are stable [1]) take the first one.

[1] "stable" means, that they keep the order. If not you must iteratore over `$uniqueCharacters` and find the one, that appears first manually.

```
$positions = array_map(
    $uniqueCharacters,
    functions ($character) use ($string) { return strpos($string, $character); }
);
$pos = min($positions);
echo "{$string[$pos]}:$pos";
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>
> Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.

secondly, `$c = $sentence[0]` and `strpos($sentence, $c)` does not gain you any more information of what you already know.

Answer (score 0):

to find a position of a substring in a string you should use the strpos method:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: He is using the strpos method?

Comment: maybe I mistaked the question, but to find the position of the first occurrence in a string strpos could be used.

Comment: This is what Im using $pos = strpos($sentence, $c);

Comment: ok, but  $sentence[0] will return only the starting char into the string. Try to look at this:

[link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php)